# Couchbase query by "index"

Tags: couchbase

I will store, in couchbase, something like this:

```
key: foo
value: { 
   some_id => bar,
   /* other fields */
}
```

for me, is easy find the value, using the key 'foo', but how I can find the key 'foo' using the 'some_id' bar (and it can returns more than one result)?

I was reading about views + where clause, it is the only way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides Couchbase views (as you mentioned), as of Couchbase version 3.x you will have [N1QL](http://www.couchbase.com/communities/n1ql) query language. You can specify "where" condition to select your json objects without having any views in place.

So as per your example, you should be able issue a query like that:

```
SELECT *
  FROM your_bucket_name
    WHERE some_id = 'bar'
```

Try out [N1QL tutorial](http://query.pub.couchbase.com/tutorial/#index)

Another way could be to utilize [Couchbase integration with ElasticSearch](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-elastic-search/) and perform search query in ES engine that will return you all keys it found based on your search criteria.